# How to make use of XAML when developing dynamically built GUI

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I want to create GUI which is divided into many separate modules which often can be dynamically added and removed to the shared canvas (Window) throughout the life cycle of my GUI-app. This is not something extraordinary, I think. Many apps use GUIs which divided on functional blocks which in turn appearing and disappearing on the screen based on current app state.

So basically, I can't make it clear for myself how can I describe such a distributed structure of GUI parts in XAML. Should I create many little XAML-files for every element on the screen that can dynamically appear and disappear and then dynamically load them? Or there is some centralized approach: when I can write XAML mostly in one place?

Comment: Use DataTemplates for different chunks of UI — implicit DataTemplates for different viewmodel types, or maybe write DataTemplateSelectors. With MVVM, WPF is a great way to write the kind of UI you want.

Comment: Yes, create different user controls with their own view models and add them all to the main window.